# Delete rows from BigTable that match a regex in BigTable

Tags: bigtable

I am looking for the cleanest/fastest way to delete rows from a BigTable cluster that match a regex. What are the best option to do so? Thanks!

Comment: Did you try smth?

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways to delete a row in BigTable but I’m not aware of any specific way to delete following a regex. You can delete row that contains a prefix by using [this method](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/reference/admin/rest/v2/projects.instances.tables/dropRowRange)

Another way to delete data from BigTable could be using this [dataflow template](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-bigtable-examples/tree/master/java/dataflow-bulk-delete)

I think that if you share with us an example of what you are trying to achieve and what you tried so far we can provide you with a more accurate answer